# How can I export a function with Moose::Exporter?

Tags: perl, oop, moose, exporter

I wanted to export a simple function from a base class that I use all over my sub classes without having to use $self->myfunc() all the time, just a simple func() call.

I tried doing this with the example from [Moose::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0205/lib/Moose/Exporter.pm)

but I didnt understand what

```
as_is     => [ 'sugar3', \&Some::Random::thing ],
```

was doing, as the example seems incomplete. sugar3 isnt defined anywhere, so I dunno where or how to use it. Can I call sugar3() in the subclass now? Is sugar3() some secret Moose thing?

and then the was this thing... literally

```
thing;
```

that was exported, but I have no idea what thing is doing since there is no example of it. Is this a function call?

Anyway, more to the point **how do you export functions like you would normally do with Exporter, but with Moose Exporter instead,** and what happens if my baseclass has 3 levels of inheritance after it, will all the sub sub classes have access to this exported function?

Comment: This isn't much of a help, but thinking about trying to mash OO inheritance and package syntax like this just gives me the heebie-jeebies. Are you sure there's not a better way to do what you're trying to do? Besides, I'm fairly certain (though I could also very easily be wrong) that a use parent 'Whatever' doesn't end up importing functions into the local package, anyway, so it doesn't sound any different than the way Exporter works.

Comment: im not trying to mash anything i just use a function call a lot to debug print and test things but I'll clean it up when im done =]. In any case I still would like to understand how this works. +1 thanks for sharing ur thoughts about this

Comment: `$self->myfunc()` and `myfunc()` are two very different things, and you shouldn't be writing a method and then trying to export it as a sub. An exported *function* will not have access to the object - that is, it is not *object oriented*.

Comment: +1 Good point. It seems like I shouldn't be trying to do this in Moose, but then why would Moose provide an exporter if we werent to export anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as_is => [ ... ]`:

> This list of function names or sub references will be exported as-is. You can identify a subroutine by reference, which is handy to re-export some other module's functions directly by reference (`\&Some::Package::function`).

`sugar3` is the name of a sub to export.

Yes, you can call `sugar3` in the subclass now if that's where you exported it to. That said, it's usually weird to export (anything but constants) to a subclass.

Yes, `thing;` is a sub call. Under `no strict;`, it could also be the same as `'thing';`.

The sub classes won't have access to the sub unless it's called as a method (e.g. `$o->thing;` instead of `thing;`). It's extremely weird to export methods, though. Create a Moose::Role to give methods to a class.

Comment: so is this essentially exporting -- using Roles? Is there a way not to have to type $self->func() everytime? -- not like Im going to die if I cant =P the problem is some of the older libary dont use Moose and I have to still use what they export, so why cant I do it in Moose instead?

Comment: @nodebunny, `$self->func()` is required for methods. I didn't say you can't export methods, I said it's extremely weird.